# Where to find a list of all cp error messages?

Tags: linux, cp

I would like to know if there is somewhere an exhaustive list of `cp` error messages. The purpose is to be able to find all `cp` errors from a log file.

For example, with the following script:

```
touch toto
cp toto mydir/toto2
cp toto3 toto4
```

`cp` prints the following errors:

```
cp: cannot create regular file 'mydir/toto2': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'toto3': No such file or directory
```

I could just `grep "cp:"` from the log file. However, it is possible that some non cp related content may contain "cp:" inside, giving an undesired result.

I would like to refine the search with specific `cp` error messages, but [man cp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cp) does not provide them and I am not able to find them all.

Is there a list somewhere with all possible `cp` error messages ?

Comment: There is no list. Inspect `cp` source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy if you grep with a regular expression:

```
egrep '^cp:' <file>
```

This way you only get lines that *start* with "cp:".

Comment: Well, indeed. I forgot about that... It's a solution (even if it does not actually answer the question ^^)